# Scan folder and output all file names in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to scan all files in a folder and output their file names. My code here only outputs the first file name of that file type

```
<cfset filetypes = arrayNew(1)>
<cfset arrayAppend(filetypes, "jpg")>
<cfset arrayAppend(filetypes, "txt")>
<cfset arrayAppend(filetypes, "pdf")>

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(filetypes)#">
    <cfdirectory
        action="list"
        directory="filepath" 
        name="Files"
        recurse = "yes"
        filter="*.#filetypes[i]#" />         
    <cfoutput>files: #Files.name#<br></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

What has gone wrong with my code?

Comment: Side note, you can apply multiple filters without looping. (The docs are wrong.) Use the pipe symbol: `filter="*.jpg|*.txt|*.pdf"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't looping over files...
It returns an object to iterate over... An query I believe.

So loop like the following

```
<Cfoutput query="Files">
#Files.name# <br>
</cfoutput>
```